# How to check what applications are using the most disk space?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-space

I have 380GB left on my SSD and was wondering how much space my applications are using. Is there a way to check this?

Comment: The title does not reflect the question.

Comment: @lhf - you can edit things to make it better :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the Finder, you can sort the Applications folder (or any other folder) by size, and let it calculate the space inside each folder in addition to sizing the flat files.

- The key command Command-Shift-A will open the Applications folder from Finder
- The key command Command-J will **Show View Options**

Then ensure the checkbox to calculate all sizes is checked. Lastly, click on the size column in the finder window (making sure you are in list view (Command-2) to sort by size. Keep clicking to reverse the sort order if the small applications get sorted to the top.

[image: Finder View Options]

You will also want to look at your home folder as well as the /Library folder to see if some applications have large media files that you might be able to delete if you don't do movie editing or need all the Garage Band loops for example.

Comment: Thank you, well the only app takes more than 5GB is Diablo 3, others are taking less than 1GB space...However I have 98GB taken as *other* when I open *about this mac* > *storage* ... any ideas ? I prefer something that can show me the information more specifically

Comment: Sure - start with list view and showing all folder sizes for the hard drive and drill down. You might also like a program like [What Size App](http://whatsizemac.com) that not only will calculate sizes, but sort the largest to the top so you can take action like remove unneeded nib files, PPC code, or just delete folders as you discover how much space they occupy.

Comment: @bmike GREAT answer. thank you, i don't know yet about this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Try *About this Mac / More info / Storage* and you'll get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run Terminal and type the following command:

```
du -s /Applications/* | sort -nr | head
```

It will show you the most space consuming applications.

For more advanced solutions, check:

- [How do I find how much disk space a program is occupying?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46714/how-do-i-find-how-much-disk-space-a-program-is-occupying)
- [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)

Answer (score 0):

[OmniDiskSweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/more)   is free and will do exactly what you are asking for.